# characters converted to dates when using write.csv

Tags: r, export-to-csv

my data frame has a column A with strings in character form

```
> df$A
[1] "2-60", "2-61", "2-62", "2-63" etc
```

I saved the table using write.csv, but when I open it with Excel column A appears formatted as date:

```
Feb-60
Feb-61
Feb-62
Feb-63
etc
```

Anyone knows what can I do to avoid this?

I tweaked the arguments of write.csv but nothing worked, and  I can't seem to find an example in Stack Overflow that helps solve this problem.

Comment: Please show the code you used to write the file

Comment: It sounds like Excel is doing the conversion, not R.

Comment: `write.csv(df, file="analysis.csv", quote=TRUE)`    I suspect it's Excel's fault, but I was hoping to do something in R so Excel does not do this.

Comment: What is the format if you read that file back into R?

Comment: @nrussell, great question. if I read "analysis.csv" back into R, I get the original format, not the dates. I combed through Excel options but couldn't find any way to deactivate this annoying automatic formatting. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution - a bit tedious, Use Import Text File in Excel, click thru the dialog boxes and in Step 3 of 3 of the Text Import Wizard, you will have an option of setting the column data format, use "Text" for the column that has "2-60", "2-61", "2-62", "2-63". If you use General (the default), Excel tries to be smart and converts the answer for you.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution that worked best for me, since I needed an output in Excel.

Answer (score 10):

As said in the comments, this is an excel behaviour, not R's. And that can't be deactivated:

> Microsoft Excel is preprogrammed to make it easier to enter dates. For
> example, 12/2 changes to 2-Dec. This is very frustrating when you
> enter something that you don't want changed to a date. Unfortunately
> **there is no way to turn this off**. But there are ways to get around it.

[Microsoft Office Article](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8)

The first suggested way around it according to the article is not helpful, because it relies on changing the cell formatting, but that's too late when you open the .csv file in excel (it's already converted to an integer representing the date).

There is, however, a useful tip:

> If you only have a few numbers to enter, you can stop Excel from
> changing them into dates by entering:
>
> - An apostrophe (‘) before you enter a number, such as ’11-53 or ‘1/47. The apostrophe isn’t displayed in the cell after you press
>   Enter.

So you can make the data display as original by using

```
vec <- c("2-60", "2-61", "2-62", "2-63")
vec <- paste0("'", vec)
```

Just remember the values will still have the apostrophe if you read them again in R, so you might have to use

```
vec <- sub("'", "", vec)
```

This might not be ideal but at least it works.

One alternative is enclosing the text in `=" "`, as an excel formula, but that has the same end result and uses more characters.

Comment: Whoever was the genius on the Excel team who made this a non-optional design decision should be slapped up the side of the head.

Comment: What amuses me is that instead of simpling creating a checkbox to disable it they write an article saying it can be very frustrating and give some ideas that are useful *if you only have a few numbers to enter*.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by saving the file using the .xlsx format by using the function

```
    write.xlsx()
```

from the package xlsx (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xlsx/versions/0.6.5)

Comment: To improve your answer try to provide more information. For example package...

Comment: Can this package save csv or is it just xlsx? I am having the same problem described above.