# Is there a way to prevent Excel from automatically forcing my character string to a date from within R?

Tags: r, excel

Within R, I have a character string ID formatted like `XX-XX` where `XX` is any integer number between 01 and 99.

However, when the numbers that make the character string could resemble a date, Excel is automatically forcing this change.

I am writing to a .csv file directly from within R using `write.csv()`.

Unfortunately, I am not able to change the ID format convention and I also require this to be controlled from within R as it is a small part of a very large automated process where people using the software do not necessarily have any understanding of the mechanics. Furthermore, configuring excel on every person who uses this systems software is not desirable but will consider it as a last resort.

Is this possible? I am open to using a different writing option like the `xlsx` package if it can provide a solution.

MWE Provided:

`# Create object with digits that will provoke the problem.`

`ID <- data.frame(x = '03-15')`

`# Write object to a csv file within the working directory.`

`write.csv(ID, file = 'problemFile.csv')`

`# Now open the .csv file in excel and view the result.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the `openxlsx` package.  This worked for me:

```
ID <- data.frame(x = '03-15')
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")
writeData(wb, "Sheet 1", x = ID)
saveWorkbook(wb, "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
openXL("test.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

[characters converted to dates when using write.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956486/characters-converted-to-dates-when-using-write-csv)

Comment: Nevermind, it won't work. maybe fileEncoding

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956486/characters-converted-to-dates-when-using-write-csv

Comment: Answers are supposed to at least give steps or a process to address the question in order to start being complete. An explanation of the steps might also be in order. Using a link to another question is not a suitable answer. Making an additional comment on that answer to another linked question does nothing to improve the answer either.

Comment: It was not my first answer, once I realized it was already answered elsewhere I edit it so the user could see it, you know, only to make sure.